# Force `sdist` to create .zip archive even on Linux

Tags: python, distutils, sdist

I know it is possible to force `sdist` to produce .zip from command line:

```
python setup.py sdist --formats=zip
```

But how to make this option a default for my `setup.py`?

I'd like to get consistency for running `setup.py sdist` on both Windows and Linux, and I choose .zip format, because I can [turn .zip into executable](http://techtonik.rainforce.org/2015/01/shipping-python-tools-in-executable-zip.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it myself from distutils docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/extending.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#creating-a-new-distutils-command), and from [distutils sources](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2db41d551a4f/Lib/distutils/command/sdist.py#l92):

```
# Override sdist to always produce .zip archive
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist as _sdist
class sdistzip(_sdist):
    def initialize_options(self):
        _sdist.initialize_options(self)
        self.formats = 'zip'

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'sdist': sdistzip},
)
```